# 404 when running node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404, ejs

Hi learning to use node and other backend components and running into this 404 when running a simple input form:

```
Not Found
404

NotFoundError: Not Found
    at /Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas-tutorial/app.js:25:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas-tutorial/node_modules/serve- 
static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/samgniel/Desktop/saas- 
tutorial/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
```

The code for the input form is:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
  <input required type="email" name="email" id="emailForm" placeholder="Your Email">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordForm" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" name="" id="" value="Signup!">
</form>
```

And the .js calling function is:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body);
});
```

Help in resolving this error would be appreciated :)

Comment: Show us what is happening on line 25 in the app.js

Comment: `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});`

Comment: ok... Your app is hitting the 404... I don't know the tutorial you followed but I can write out a way for your code to work properly

Comment: sure, that would be great

Comment: If you paste back-end code then it may be help full to solve early

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are not returning any response to the client. One way you can correct that is to use the send function in the res object that express provides.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World') // this can also take an object as response. res.send({ msg: 'hello world' })
});
```

It may also help to reove this line `ok comment out this line app.use(function(req, res, next) { next(createError(404)); });`

Hope this helps.

Comment: same 404 after trying this

Comment: ok comment out this line `app.use(function(req, res, next) { next(createError(404)); });`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay... I was trying to host it on codesandbox...

You can make your Node Side like this

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at PORT:${PORT}`);
});
```

And Create an HTML file where you will consume the API using fetch API

Something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
      <input
        required
        type="email"
        name="email"
        id="emailForm"
        placeholder="Your Email"
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        id="passwordForm"
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <input type="submit" name="" id="submit" value="Signup!" />
    </form>

    <script>
      const emailForm = document.querySelector('#emailForm');
      const passwordForm = document.querySelector('#passwordForm');
      const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

      const submitFetch = (url, data) => {
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          redirect: 'follow',
          referrer: 'no-referrer',
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(response => response.json());
      };

      submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
          email: emailForm.value,
          password: emailForm.value
        };
        submitFetch('http://localhost:5000/signup', data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Incase you want to see it live... I hosted it on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-cannon-x1wu1